# Can I use SQL Server security to control access to my (database first) ASP.net application? How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, security

I've been a SQL server developer thus far, but I'm now having to make an ASP.net MVC5 application to allow users to access the data. Previously, all access was via (SSL encrypted) ODBC connections which were secured using SQL Server logins. I'm comfortable with SQL Server security management; I have a bunch of defined roles and access is usually granted or denied at the schema level. This also allows me to easily monitor/audit access and data changes.

Everything I read about ASP.net seems to want me to make a single user for the application, with very expansive read/write permissions, and then to lock these down piecemeal at the application level. I'd really rather not do that, if possible - I'd like to have users provide their SQL server uid/password at runtime and determine their rights based on that. I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is this even possible? It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere as
   an option.
2. Is there a compelling reason why I shouldn't do this, even if it is
   possible? I'm not totally averse to learning a new security paradigm
   if it's what I need to do to keep things really safe.

Note that for various reasons, using Windows authentication isn't going to be possible here.

Comment: Where would you store the user's SQL password so you can connect to the database?

Comment: I'd construct the connection string at runtime, I imagine

Comment: Your application will connect to the database with a connection string. If your users are providing their credentials at runtime then you could simply generate a connection string specific to that user at runtime. Depending on the number of concurrent users you may have issues with your connection pool though.

Comment: But how will you get the password to put in the connection string?

Comment: @SLaks, there are many ways to securely store credentials. One of them is to not store them at all, and prompt at runtime. Another is to store them in a separate database that only this application has access to. Another is to store them in a configuration file outside of any publicly accessible directory. I could go on and on...

Comment: @AdamEdison-MusicEducator storing passwords in any location where they can be read as plain text is a bad idea. Prompting at run time is the only way to do this safely.

Comment: I have to say that having a separate login for each user sounds like a nightmare. You would have to grant exec on every single new procedure to every single user. The connection pool could also easily get overloaded on even a reasonably busy site. You are still going to have to manage access within your application so isn't gaining you anything.

Comment: @AdamEdison-MusicEducator: After the user logs in, how would you get the DB password for a later request? Storing end-user passwords in retrievable format is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use end-user credentials directly for your database.

The fundamental problem with this approach is that you'd need to be able to retrieve the end-user's password to connect to the database.

This means that if your systems are ever compromised, you'll leak passwords for other sites (for users who reuse passwords).

As a compromise, you can make the DB password an iterated hash of the end-user's password.
However, you'd still need to store that (perhaps encrypted) in the login cookie, which is generally also a bad idea.

Comment: That is a straw-man argument. Review my comment above where I say that you can prompt for the password at runtime. I'll clarify my answer. Saying "don't do this" is not an answer, because the application needs to access the database. So therefore, you are implying that no CRUD application has ever been built securely.

Comment: @AdamEdison-MusicEducator: Prompting at runtime makes no sense in a web application.  Storing them anywhere defeats some of the purpose, since attackers can now just look up anyone's password.

Comment: "What's your password" *user provides password* "kthx" *stores cleartext password in memory while the user is logged in*

Comment: @Will: And then anytime your process is recycled, all users are logged out.

Comment: This also makes it impossible, insecure, or quite tricky to do any kind of scheduled job (eg, notification emails) that isn't in direct response to an authenticated request.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with storing the database connection information in a configuration file that only the application has access to.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy: Yes, unless the database connection string contains _end-user passwords_.

Comment: @SLaks My answer did not propose end-user passwords be stored in the database connection string. They would be users only granted for the application itself. Can you please remove my downvote? I will clarify my answer.

Comment: @SLaks I will remove your downvote if you clarify that "don't do this" means "don't expose database user credentials in your application at all" and not "don't allow the application to connect to the database". I think we both have good arguments, and depending on what the OP wants to do, they would pick their solution for their problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have users provide their SQL server uid/password at
>   runtime and determine their rights based on that. .. Is this even
>   possible? It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere as an option.

Definitely possible. You could use ***OWIN Cookie Authentication Middleware***, and store both username and password inside claims. Then construct connection string on-the-fly every times application needs to access database.

Although it is ***not easy to decrypt the authentication cookie on SSL*** *as of today*, you will have to keep in mind that both username and ***plain password*** will be sending to server on every page request. *It might be compliance issue, if you are required to meet.*

*Although you could use Session State, but it is **not a good practice to store plain password in server memory either**.*

> Is there a compelling reason why I shouldn't do this, even if it is
>   possible? I'm not totally averse to learning a new security paradigm
>   if it's what I need to do to keep things really safe.

Although the approach is ***very common for windows applications*** which access straight to database (without web service), it is ***not common in web applications***.

It is ok, if you have a couple of users. However, if you have a lot of users come and go, it becomes full time jobs to configure security settings in SQL Server for every user. In addition, ***you cannot restrict who can view what pages.***

It is why web application normally keeps the authorization logic inside the application itself. So, we can restrict page access using ***[AuthroizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)***.  If you want to go that route, then I highly recommend you to look at ***ASP.NET Identity***.

Comment: Why do this rather that simply store the credentials in a configuration file stored on the server? This way there is no need for encryption or prompting. The credentials will be as safe as the security around the server itself.

Comment: We should ***never store plain password in a file*** which sit in a web server. In this question, we are not talking about single username and password like a connection string; we are talking about multiple user's username and password. If web server gets compromise, hacker could use those passwords right away at other sites. ***If we need to store users' password in persistent storage, we should always use one-way hash with random salt before storing them such as SHA-512.*** *Btw, I did not down-vote either of answers.*

Comment: Right, my proposed solution was to use credentials stored plainly in a file on the web server, which only has read permissions for the application runner on its own isolated group, and not to use actual DB user credentials. The credentials are for that application only. If the web server gets hacked, you remove that one DB user from your system and push an updated file with new credentials once secure again.

Answer (score -1):

**;TLDR**

The best naive solution is to use a specialized user for your application only, and the credentials would be stored in a configuration file on your webserver, outside of public access (accessible to the application only).

In this manner, no user credentials are compromised, and if your application is hacked, you have only granted it limited functionality (and you can easily change the credentials to new ones once the threat has been eliminated).

**Here are the things you don't want to do and why:**

1. If you have an ODBC connection created in whatever middle tier you want (it doesn't matter if it's .NET, Java, Python, PHP, whatever), you are supplying credentials to obtain a secure connection - either by connection parameters, or a connection string like this:

   Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
   Pwd=myPassword;

Or you are setting properties on an object in memory, which accomplishes the same thing.

So, you could choose to use an individual user's authentication against that database in place of a special database user that has all permissions, to limit the permissions of that ODBC connection.

2. Reasons not to do this:

   - You will be unable to distinguish whether your application is making a change in the database or whether that user logged in to your database and made the change.
   - You expose your database login within your application. Depending on where it's being deployed, this could be a security risk if you don't prevent against brute force attacks (or any of kind of attack that could compromise a user's credentials).
   - You are not able to define precisely what your application is allowed to do. Someone could create a super user in your database, then log in through your application, and take complete control of your database.
   - Do not create a single user for your application and give it **all** permissions. If there is a bug in your application, it may result in the database being left in an inconsistent state (bad data, missing entries, etc). Only give it the permissions it needs for specific operations - lock it down as much as possible.